# How can I pass a function to a header button in react navigation's navigationOptions?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**What I want to do:**

I have a screen with an add button on the header.
When I click it a modal opens and it should pass in a function into this opened modal.

But I can't make it work because I don't use classes.

This is how I do it:

```
PlayerScreen.navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => {
  console.log("screen props", screenProps);
  return {
    title: "Spieler",
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("AddPlayerModal", {addPlayer})}
        title="+"
        color="black"
      />
    )
  };
};
```

The problem is `addPlayer` is a function from the PlayerScreen Component. So I have no way to access it like this. 
Is there a way to pass the function in somehow? I think I could use a class and then I should have access in the static `navigationOptions` method right?

But I want to make it work without creating a class.
So is there a way?

**What have I tried:**

I tried to set the param like this on the `PlayerScreen` component:

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setParams({ addPlayer });
  }, []);
```

But in the modal when I do this:

`const addPlayer = navigation.getParam("addPlayer");`

`addPlayer` is undefined.

Thank you in advance, Geralt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
PlayerScreen.navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => {
  const { params = {} } = navigation.state
  return {
    title: "Spieler",
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("AddPlayerModal", { addPlayer: params.addPlayer })}
        title="+"
        color="black"
      />
    )
  };
};

useEffect(() => {
  navigation.setParams({ addPlayer });
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. However I switched over to redux now, because on this method the state somehow didn't get persisted. So every time i add a new name it replaces the old name. With Redux everything works perfectly now.